# Issues using "String.prototype.substring"

Tags: javascript, string, class, methods, substring

I have some issues using the `replace` method for javascript strings :

I created a class that contains this method :

```js
    setDataAt(pos, value) {
        this.#data = this.#data.substring(0, pos)+value+this.#data.substring(pos+1);
    }
```

but when I use it, the data is truncated as there wasn't any `+this.#data.substring(pos+1);`...
Per example, if my object `obj` has as `#data` attribute `"Hello world"`, after making `obj.setDataAt(5, '.')`, the `#data` attribute will be `"Hello."` and not `"Hello.world"`

**EDIT :**

My issue doesn't seems to appair when I use it directly (below is a little part of my original code, all that is used into ma issue, and it totally work).
But when I use it from my web page, it gives issues :

How to fix that? Thanks for all your answers

**Another Edit** :

The problem is that in my website page, the `pos` var isn't an integer, but a string.
I have to replace all `pos` by `parseInt(pos)` to make it work correctly.

Thanks a lot @Nick_Parsons!

Comment: I can't reproduce this ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/4pvfghjt/)). Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: https://www.flopcreation.fr/block_creator.php; then open the inspector, when you'll click the size before and after your click will be shown. Just wait 30 seconds I#ll note all of this

Comment: the https://www.flopcreation.fr/block_creator.php page is ready for debugging instructions. If you don't understand something, please make me know

Comment: Please see the second link in my above comment. Can you make a reproducible example, that shows your issue with as minimal code as possible to reproduce it (linking to your entire project offsite doesn't help)? You can [create a runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to help.

Comment: Ok I'll try. Just wait a few hours because I am busy

Comment: In your example, instead of "console.log(data)", use "txtres=document.createElement('pre');txtres.textContent=r;document.body.appendChild(txtres);" or "alert(r);"

Comment: In a snippet it worked successfully with "Hello World" as your program... but it doesn't work in my own javascript page so I don't know how to ask my question... ^^'

Comment: That's part of your debugging process. If it works in the snippet but not in your real code then something is different. You can start commenting out (disabling) different parts of your code to see what might be impacting it. Double-check that your variables store what you think they hold etc.

Comment: If it helps `pos` in your website link is a string. Convert it to a number, eg: `+pos+1` will add instead of concatenate 1 to `pos` like it currently is doing.

Comment: Ok, I'll see that but I was asking for which data has been wrong typed or something like this... Thanks a lot I go to see

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I can't answer my own question. How do I finish this question?